# MySQL Join: Omit ALL repeating rows IF one row meets a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Given the following example tables

```
TABLE_A
-----
 ID  
-----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5

TABLE_B
---------------------------
 TABLE_A_ID        DETAIL
---------------------------
    1               val_x
    2               val_x
    2               val_y
    4               val_y
    5               val_other
```

I am doing a left join on these two tables and get the following output

```
-------------------------------
   TABLE_A_ID        DETAIL
-------------------------------
       1              val_x
       2              val_y
       2              val_x
       3              null
       4              val_y
       5              val_other
```

This is as I expect from a left join.

The problem I have is that I also want to remove rows that have `DETAIL` = val_y AND ALL rows that have a repeating `TABLE_A_ID` IF any row in the group has a `DETAIL` = val_y

So the output I need is;

```
-------------------------------
   TABLE_A_ID        DETAIL
-------------------------------
       1              val_x
       3              null
       5              val_other
```

I have tried using `GROUP_BY TABLE_A_ID` and `HAVING DETAIL != val_y` but that doesn't seem to work. I think for obvious reasons as `GROUP_BY` and `HAVING` are for aggregates and eliminating values that are less than or greater than right?

Is there a way to do this in MySQL or am I asking too much?

Note: These are EXAMPLE tables. They do not reflect a production system, so would appreciate no comments or answers outside the scope of the question and example - it just confuses things.

Comment: How are you getting the `null` row with an inner join? That looks like the result of an outer join.

Comment: ah sorry, i meant left join - will fix

Comment: Hm, a single val_y value should _not_ be eliminated?

Comment: see update for more info

Comment: Now your example doesn't match the description. Why was ID 4 removed when it's not repeating?

Comment: your are right - will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another `LEFT JOIN` to eliminate ids with a 'val_y' value;

```
SELECT a.id as table_a_id, b1.detail 
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b1 ON a.id = b1.table_a_id
LEFT JOIN table_b b2 ON a.id = b2.table_a_id AND b2.detail = 'val_y'
WHERE b2.detail IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9348c/1) (updated with new sample data)

Comment: You're not checking for repeated rows with the same id.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sub1.id table_a_id, sub1.detail
FROM (
    SELECT a.id, detail
    FROM table_a a
    LEFT JOIN table_b b on a.id = b.table_a_id) sub1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT table_a_id
    FROM table_b
    WHERE detail = 'val_y') sub2 
ON sub1.id = sub2.table_a_id
WHERE sub2.table_a_id IS NULL
```

The `sub2` subquery finds all the IDs that meet your criteria for removal. This is then joined with the original query to filter out those IDs.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ecf5/1)

Comment: thanks @baramar - i think I made my example TOO simple given some of the odd answers below. Have updated question. Does your solution still hold? It looks good from first inspection. Will try out

Comment: sorry, you were right. Had missed a very important part out of the question. I don't want val_y in the result at all - single rows and grouped

Comment: Check my latest fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ecf5/1 to ensure it meets your desired results. Your example doesn't have any repeated IDs other than the one that should be removed, mine has a non-removed repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT b.table_a_id, b.detail
   FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
   GROUP BY b.table_a_id
   HAVING COUNT( b.table_a_id ) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
select * from table_b where table_a_id not in (
    select TABLE_A_ID from TABLE_B where detail = 'val_y'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below will help you

```
Select a.ID ,b.Detail
From Table1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id ,count(*) from Table2 group by id having count(*) =1 ) b
ON a.id = b.ID
```

Comment: You're only supposed to remove repeated rows if `val_y` is among the details in the group.

Comment: ok now query will return all the record in table1 and join table2 with unique record